# Open a shared link in facebook to open in native app if installled in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am struggling with one thing. Below is the scenario:

I have a website which has a feature to share a link with facebook.
What I want is if someone has the facebook app installed in the iPhone and clicks on the link, it should open it in the app to which that link belongs, if that app is installed.

Could you help me? How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the URL scheme, which can be found here

[Facebook iOS URL Scheme](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook)

You will need to open the URL like so

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.some URL.com"]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response . But I am looking for something else.Lets say my ios app name is ABC and and link is posted from the site on the facebook timline "http://abc.com/shr/test" and when i tab this link on facebook native app , it should open the url by launching my app if app is installed on the device . Hope you understand.

Comment: Oh I see, what you want is to go to the facebook develop site, and edit your app settings so that it provides a link to your app's url scheme.

Comment: So you mean in the facebook app setting page (under Native iOS App), I need to provide the details of our app ?

Comment: Thanks Amit for responding.Have you ever worked on MDM (Mobile device management) where we can distribute the app to multiple users at a time ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check and open some specifics applications using url which they are shared their url scheme [here](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes).

For example with facebook, you can check if the user has the app installed :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile"]];
```

And call this method to open the application :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile"]];
```